# Составной индекс на нескольких полях: нужны ли индексы по отдельным полям?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Есть некоторая таблица в базе SQL Server 2008 R2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Три столбца, три индекса.

Создана она при помощи Entity Framework, всё просто:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int GroupBuyingId { get; set; }

    public GroupBuying GroupBuying { get; set; }

    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }

    public Contact Participant { get; set; }
}
```

Через какое-то время прилетело требование наложить ограничение уникальности на поля GroupBuyingId  и ParticipantId, ну я и сделал:

```
public class OrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
    {
        builder.HasIndex(x => new { x.GroupBuyingId, x.ParticipantId }).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

Но перед тем как применять миграцию - автоматически глянул, что там создано:

```
public partial class UniqueConstraintForOrder : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Orders_GroupBuyingId",
            table: "Orders");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Orders_GroupBuyingId_ParticipantId",
            table: "Orders",
            columns: new[] { "GroupBuyingId", "ParticipantId" },
            unique: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Orders_GroupBuyingId_ParticipantId",
            table: "Orders");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Orders_GroupBuyingId",
            table: "Orders",
            column: "GroupBuyingId");
    }
}
```

И вот что мне непонятно. Создаётся новый индекс по двум полям - это правильно. Но зачем-то сносится один из существующих индексов (кстати, почему не оба?), видимо из расчёта, что можно будет использовать составной?

Что вообще в подобных случаях рекомендуется делать - оставлять один составной индекс или составной + два отдельных?

Понятно, что во втором случае объём занимаемый индексом будет больше, плюс соответственно время на его обработку при вставке новых значений, а что насчёт скорости выборок?

Будет ли составной индекс работать так же эффективно, как и одиночные?

Answer (score 4):

Разница для составного индекса и индекса с одним полем заключается в длине ключа, чем длиннее ключ, тем больше операций чтения при поиске для большой таблицы придется выполнить движку.

В приведенном примере нет смысла держать дубль индекса, так как разница в длине ключа несущественна, практического выигрыша по чтениям не будет.

Поиск всегда использует первое поле ключа индекса, поэтому второй индекс не удаляется, так как он построен по другому (не по первому в составном) полю.

Comment: Почему операций чтения больше при увеличении длины ключа ? количество узлов двоичного дерева поиска является двоичным логарифмом количества уникальных значений в индексе, вне зависимости от их длины. (Если не рассматривать самого списка строк, подходящих под ключ, размер которого в любом случае прямо пропорционален количеству записей таблицы) Да, конечно более длинные ключи занимают в страницах индекса больше места, но это приведет к необходимости дополнительных чтений при действительно большой длине ключей.

Comment: Имел ввиду конечно количество узлов, которые надо пройти для осуществления поиска, т.е. высоту дерева

Comment: Вроде так и написано: "В приведенном примере нет смысла держать дубль индекса, так как разница в длине ключа несущественна, практического выигрыша по чтениям не будет"

Comment: Написано то более менее правильно. Просто сама фраза о прямой зависимости количества чтений от длины ключа не корректна. Даже если бы длина ключа была 20 и 100 байт, но при этом добавление второго поля не сильно увеличивало бы уникальность, то количество чтений для получения узлов дерева бы не изменилось. Если у вас есть индекс с значениями 1, 2, 3, 4 и индекс с "aaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbb", "cccccccccc", "dddddddddd" то уровней индекса будет все равно только 2, корень, делящий общее пространство ключей примерно пополам и две страницы листьев левой и правой половины

Answer (score 3):

Составной индекс по полям (A, B) всегда может использоваться вместо индекса (A), но не может использоваться вместо индекса (B). Ну, если это стандартный B-Tree индекс.

Тем не менее, поиск по простому индексу (A) будет чуть быстрее, чем по составному (A, B), из-за бо́льшего числа записей в одном ключевом узле дерева. Но на интах вы этого не заметите.